# How do you add XML prolog in javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am trying to send an XML document via SOAP to a server that requires the payload XML to contain an XML prolog e.g., `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`.  The following is very similar to the code I'm using:

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
SOAPPart soapPart = getSoapMessage().getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
soapHeader = envelope.getHeader();
soapBody = envelope.getBody();

soapHeader.detachNode();
SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = soapBody.addBodyElement(getEnvelope().createName("my_element_name"));
bodyElement.addAttribute(getEnvelope().createName("my_attribute_name"), "my_attribute_value");
bodyElement.addChildElement("my_child_element");
...
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but adding a XML prolog in the middle of an XML document invalid. A SOAPMessage is already a XML Document, and the SOAP Body is nested, so you can not repeat the prolog. Could you explain what the result end result you seek would look like ?

Comment: The end result would look like:`<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>     <my_element_name my_attribute_name="my_attribute_value">    <my_child_element>...`

Answer (score 1):

A XML prolog can only exist at the very start of a XML document.

From the XML Specification available here : http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#sec-prolog-dtd

> The document type declaration must appear before the first element in the document.

Writing a prolog in the middle of a SOAP document, therefore, is invalid - and I doubt you'll find a SOAP library or implementation that will allow you to do that. There may be a requirement you and/or your "client" have misunderstood in requiring this.

You can try a XML validator softare (e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp ), it should report an error for your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to add xml prolog declaration right before the first SOAP `Envelope` tag:

```
soapMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, Boolean.TRUE.toString());
```